# Google Maps library loading blocks the page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use the following HTML tag to load the Google Maps API :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

However, it is blocking the loading everything that's below it in the HTML until the script is loaded by the browser.

Is there a way to make this loading non-blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load it asynchronously. Check out this part of the docs:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async

Comment: The "Async" section seems to have been removed from the documentation... Looking at [this page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async), the source contains a sample of asynchronous loading of the Google Maps library

Answer (score 4):

This code gives you a defer function that takes an url and an optional callback.
It asynchronously loads your script without blocking page rendering.
I've put in a protection so it won't load the same scritp twice, so you can naively call it as many times as you like.

```
defer = (function () {
    var urls = [];

    return function (url, callback) {
        var inc;

        if (url && urls.indexOf(url) === -1) {
            inc = document.createElement('script');
            inc.async = true;
            inc.src = url;
            inc.onload = callback || function () {};
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(inc);
        }
    }
}());

defer('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
```

This works for any external javascript that doesn't fail on async loading.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip, but I'd rather use the "official" way in this case

Comment: It's the same thing. Mine just gives you a function that can load arbitrary urls instead of google maps specificly.

Comment: @Munter it there any situation that async loading fails for some scripts? i am asking this question with respect to your last line in your answer.